# What is this plant which looks like chives?

Tags: identification, chives

- Found in West Michigan zone 5b.
- It tolerates cool and heat well. It emerges about the same time as chives but it does not have a single hollow stem like chives. It has an occasional leaf that comes off the stem like grass.
- The stem is very skinny like grass, but strong and tall, it's 24" tall now.
- Stem does not appear to be hollow.
- Flowers look a lot like chive as they appear at the end of a stalk in a bunch when it's still cool, when temps in the mid-60s F.
- Now the flowers are gone there are seed-like structures on top each with a long skinny chive-like green "stem". "Seeds" are brownish red.
- When breaking a stem it does not smell like onions or garlic.
- It grows among other grasses near a fence in full sun.
- It comes back every year on its own even surviving harsh Michigan winters.
- Could it be some type of reed?
- I'm familiar with equisetum (aka rushes, horse tails), chives, onions, leeks, garlic and it's none of those. I even have top onions and it's not that either.
- I thought it might be a corkscrew rush but it's not cork screwy (unless that happens later in summer). Besides it thrives in dry sandy soil.

[image]

Better pic:

[image]

Comment: Does it smell like onion?  If not I believe it is nut sedge.

Comment: I know what nut sedge is, it's not that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's wild garlic ([Allium Vineale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allium_vineale)). They're a weird-looking type of ornamental onion. Wouldn't smell any more like an onion than most of the decorative types (which is barely if at all, depending on growing conditions.)

Comment: Thank you. I did not know some *Allium* did not smell of onion.

Answer (score 1):

It is an *Allium*. Allium is often viviparous (the small children plants growing from the *flower*), and characteristic is also the horizontal spate bract (the light brown "leave" just below the *flower*).

I'm not so sure about the which garlic species is it. (wild garlics are difficult to determine).